# Problem when debugging Mac application

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to run an existing old mac os targeted application. When I try to run the application I got an error like as follows,

No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=ppc, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

I am very new to Mac osx can you guys please help me?

Thank you,
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Go to Project Properties expand Targets, select Leaves, right-click Get Info. 
Update the base SDK to the version you are currently using.

Hope that solves the issue !

Comment: @DumCode,  I am using MAC OS 10.6 I target my application BaseSdk to that. still I am getting the same error, Can you please suggest?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your code. I was having same problem but after chaning SDK it solveed. let me check for soe other solution

Answer (score 0):

Set your targets ARCH build setting to "standard (32/64-bit) intel".